# How would one say "fading away" in Greek and Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, greek, word-request

In music, the Italian term *morendo* means "fading or dying away". This fairly transparently comes from *morior*. But *morior* to me suggests the moment of death, rather than a gradual decline, and is also a fairly morbid word.

If I wanted an adjective (or participle) for "fading away" or "in decline", are there better alternatives to *moriēns*? I'm interested in both Greek and Latin.

ETA: Example sentences:

> The Roman empire was **in decline** for a significant period before its actual fall.
>   We sat by the ocean at dusk, watching the sunlight **fading away**.
>   He would have preferred a quick death rather than **fading away** like this.

Comment: Perhaps *occidens, occidentis*.

Comment: @Anonym Declining? That's a good suggestion; consider expanding it into an answer.

Comment: My sense is that at least Greek (less sure about Latin) wouldn't use the same word for literal fading away (e.g. sunlight) and metaphorical decline. English metaphors rarely translate well into Greek.

Comment: @TKR That's fair, and to be expected. Either one (or better yet both) would make a good answer.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Woodhouse's English-Greek dictionary](https://www.lib.uchicago.edu/efts/Woodhouse/)? Looking up "fade", "decline" etc. there will give you some Greek options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**LATIN**

***senescens*** (from *senescere* - to grow old, weak, feeble; to waste away; to wane, fall off, decline)

Can be used literally, naturally, of someone growing weak with old age, but also figuratively:

> *et Hannibalem ipsum iam et fama senescere et viribus*
>
> and Hannibal himself now was in decline, in both reputation and
>   strength

Livy, *History of Rome*, 29.3

Can also be used more figuratively:

> *senescet amor*
>
> love will fade away

Ovid, *Ars Amatoria*, 3.594

**GREEK**

**μαραινόμενος** (from μαραίνομαι - to die away; to waste away; to slowly go out; to abate)

Can be used of people:

> καὶ τὸ σῶμα … οὐκ ἐμαραίνετο
>
> and the body … was not wasted away

Thucydides, *Peloponnesian War*, 2.49

Can also be used to describe inanimate things:

> φλὸξ ἐμαράνθη
>
> [the] fire died down

Homer, *Iliad*, 9.213

> μαραινομένου τοῦ πνεύματος
>
> with the wind dying away

Plutarch, *Pyrrhus*, 15

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that I agree with your premise:
*morior,* 'die,' gives *moriendum,* 'a dying.'
Could the Italian have mutated, through popular association, from morando?
 *Moror*  comes in three forms from three different roots; *mŏs* (usage) and *mōrus* (silly) are dead ends; but what about *mora*, delay?

> *morans, morantes,* lingering.

Another musical term

> *Con sordini* 'with a mute'

suggest *sordeo.* The problem is *sorditus*  had connotations in classical Latin of meanness, grime, decay.

May I suggest *cadens* as the most promising. There is the musical association with *'cadence,'* and a quotation from Horace;

> *Cadentia verba.* 'words dying away;'

Comment: The gerund of the Italian verb *morire* (from Latin *mori*) is indeed *morendo*. [This verb is somewhat irregular in Italian](http://www.italian-verbs.com/italian-verbs/conjugation.php?parola=morire), unlike in Latin.

Comment: +1! Where are the *cadentia verba* from, for reference?